# Xcode Storyboard workflow loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I've set up a storyboard which has in it a loop. I start with the form view, the user signs and after that it goes back to home. From home you can do a form entry again. So this goes on and on. Does this affect the memory when I have more than 40 UIViews in my stack of navigation Controller? If yes, how can I jump back to the home screen after the user signed up? Or how can I close the Views which were used in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html

is the very first iOS tutorial and explains how to do exactly that: Two storyboards, and going forth and back between them. You'll always be using the same views really. Unless you do it all by hand and push forty storyboards on the stack.